# how to create fuse buttons using Google cardboard sdk

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

i am creating a VR app with gui buttons. i want to trigger the button if user keeps the button for active for a specified time. Like the one explained in [Google design patterns](http://www.google.com/design/spec-vr/interactive-patterns/controls.html#).

Here is a youtube link on [how to animate fuse buttons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6sL0ffosds) in Mobile VR apps

Comment: You really should show some effort put into solving the problem before posting a question. Please refer to the sites FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to place a UI element in world space. Add a collider to it. Then, use the Gaze provided by the Cardboard SDK to check for a collision. If your UI element detects a gaze, it starts off a timer and animates a fuse. If the gaze leaves the UI element before the timer reaches 0, you do noting. Otherwise, activate the fuse button.

Comment: can you provide a sample for me. I Placed UI button, checked GazeInput, added a eventTrigger (Point Enter) for the button. But could not able to understand how to animate fuse.

Comment: I have updated my question with youtube help link also